# Silverlight transparent textbox background

Tags: silverlight, textbox, transparency

I have a RadGridView (from Telerik) and I'm trying to be able to select the content of a cell.

So I have a cell template :

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceStrings}, Path=ResourceStrings.Value}"
                                        DataMemberBinding="{Binding Value}" UniqueName="Value" Width="2*">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True" Style="{StaticResource ReadOnlyStyle}"  />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

With my Style for the TextBox :

```
<Style x:Key="ReadOnlyStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement">
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="ReadOnly"/>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                        <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Opacity="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="1">
                        <Grid>
                            <Border x:Name="MouseOverBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="ContentElement" BorderThickness="0" IsTabStop="False" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualElement" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Background="#A5F7F7F7" BorderBrush="#A5F7F7F7" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                    <Border x:Name="FocusVisualElement" Margin="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#FF6DBDD1" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the result :

[image: Not invisible TextBox]

How can I manage to remove this white background ?

Thanks

edit : In fact, We already had a textbox style that works with transparency and it works... I will post it later...

Comment: I can see that you set the `Background` to `Transparent` and even overwrite the `TextBox` `Template`, so it should indeed be transparent...so maybe the white stuff is not caused by the `TextBox` but it is rather the background of your `RadGridView` or caused by the row template? Do you have `XamlSpy`?

Comment: Thx for the answer. I don't have XamlSpy and I am not very confortable with Xaml yet... So it could be a simple solution... I will try to apply the transparency in parent controls

Comment: @gab : Instead of applying transparency in parent control, you can try by changing background color of immediate parent of this textbox.